# Выбрать дочерние элементы не содержащие потомков ul>li

Tags: css

Есть список типа `ul>li`.

Нужно выделить все `li` которые не содержат в себе `ul`, то есть дочерних элементов. Например задать `color:red;`

Как это сделать ?

Comment: На данный момент это невозможно: родительского селектора в css3 нет. Такое можно реализовать на `js` или `php`

Answer (score 0):

Так не получится.
Но можно сделать от обратного:

```
li {color:red;} /* делаем красными все */
li ul,
li li {color:black;} /* те, в которых есть дочерние списки, стилим как надо */
```